# How to find the maximum edge difference of a DAG?

Tags: c++, graph, c++14

I have a directed acyclic weighted graph. It can contain multiple trees. I have to find a path from the graph. Starting and finishing node is not specific. I can start from any node and finish my traversal in any node I want. 
Now I have to find a valid path where,
res = (maximum edge weight of the path - minimum edge weight of the path) is highest.
No need to output the path. Only showing the 'res' value would be enough.

[image: The graph]

In the picture there is a sample graph given. 
Here I can choose the path 1 --> 3 --> 4 --> 6. So highest weight difference would be 8.

How to find the highest weight difference?

Comment: I don't understand how your weight calculation works. Can you explain it?

Comment: In the given graph, I can choose the path 1 --> 3 --> 4 --> 6.
weight of edge 1 -> 3 is 1.
weight of edge 3 -> 4 is 4.
weight of edge 4 -> 6 is 9.
Here maximum weight is 9 and minimum weight is 1.
So highest weight difference would be (9-1)=8.

Comment: Are your weights strictly positive?

Comment: 0 <= weight <= 10^9

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is dynamic programming not permitted here?

Comment: because I have weakness in dp. so looking for a solution except dp

Comment: I think [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) would work, slightly modified to keep track of heaviest and lightest edge for each path, rather than total weight.

Comment: 1 <= node <= 10^5. So I can't use floyd-warshall here